# how do I get the output answer 4 decimal places

Tags: java

I need to round the outputs to 4 decimal places but I am not quite sure on how to do that my thing runs exactly how I want it too just need to round off the last decimals off too 4 places

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //Needed for the Scanner class  

public class SphereCalculations
{    
public static void main(String[] args)  //all the action happens here!    
{   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    double radius;
    double volume;
    double surfaceArea;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Sphere Calculator. ");
    System.out.print( "Enter radius of sphere: " );
    radius = input.nextDouble();


    volume = ((4.0 / 3.0) * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3)));
    surfaceArea = 4 * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));


    System.out.println("The Results are: ");
    System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
    System.out.println("Sphere volume is: " + volume);
    System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area is: " + surfaceArea);
}
}
```

Output:

```
Radius: 7.5
Volume: 1767.1459
Surface Area: 706.8583
```

Comment: and I made the output that but when I run the script it is like 11 decimals long

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster

Comment: you can use `printf` or `DecimalFormat`

Comment: I'm usually lazy like this `Math.round(num*1000)/1000` because it works more similarly across languages, but it is and always will be better to follow the advice above ;)

Comment: @RobinKanters That technique doesn't actually work with floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("Sphere Surface Area is: %.4f%n", surfaceArea);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you need more control, you can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which has many more formatting options. This is especially helpful if you want to print out a double in scientific notation.

```
//specify a number locale, some countries use other symbols for the decimal mark
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
if(f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    DecimalFormat d = (DecimalFormat) f;
    d.applyPattern("#.0000"); //zeros are non optional, use # instead if you don't want that
    System.out.println(d.format(surfaceArea));
}
```